# Using DOMParser to render html is a good way?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm thinking to create a website for chrome and firefox.
Rendering html element dynamicaly, is using DOMParser like the code snippet below bad way?
I googled 'DOMParser' and didn't see any codes in this use case.
I would like to know its best practice or the general way to do it.

```
var core = {};
var someHtml = '<div class="test1"><div class="test2">this string could be more complicated</div></div>';

core.onReady = function(){
    var parser = new DOMParser()
        , parsed = parser.parseFromString(someHtml, 'text/html')
        , element = parsed.body.firstChild;
    document.body.appendChild(element);
};
```

Comment: How do you make sure that onReady is ever called?

Comment: I want to make it able to be accessed by "getElementById" or "getElementsByClassName"

Comment: You might want to use a JavaScript framework like jQuery.

Comment: I am challenging without jQuery to understand JavaScript deeply.

Comment: There are better fields to learn about in JavaScript then the DOM methods. They really suck. I recommend learning about function chaining, lambda, closures, OOP in JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this. Especially if you want to test if the HTML is valid before adding it to the page.

Generally, most people will do something like:

```
document.body.innerHTML += someHtml;
```

From a speed point of view, you're unlikely to notice a massive performance hit by using the DOMParser unless you're doing this with a lot of HTML.

http://jsperf.com/html-parsing-performance-element-innerhtml-vs-domparser/2

Comment: Is is possible to access the dom after inserting html in this way?

Comment: After inserted html to "innerHTML" property, is it possible to access the inserted element by "getElementById"?

Comment: Yes. If you had an element with an ID. In your example, you don't

Comment: Don't think you can, at least not in Chrome. At least not for me, I've had to use queryselector(#id) as a substitute of getElementById